# Importing modules with gm2

Tags: modula-2

I am doing a little programming exercise in Modula2. I am using the [gm2](http://www.nongnu.org/gm2/) compiler
on Ubuntu Linux (10.04).

I have gotten some code to compile but I am unable to import certain
modules which, to my understanding, should be included in the compiler distribution.
For example, if I try to import from the TimeDate module

```
FROM TimeDate IMPORT Time, GetTime;
```

which is documented [here](http://www.nongnu.org/gm2/gm2-libs-pimtimedate.html), I get the error:

```
$ gm2 -flibs=pim -c SortUtil.mod

failed to find definition module TimeDate.def
```

According to [the documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/gm2/compiler_options.html), the option -flibs=pim should give access to
the TimeDate module (which is part of the PIM libraries).

Does anyone have any experience with this compiler? Do I need some extra command-line
parameters or do I need to install some extra packages?

Comment: Have you verified that TimeDate.def exists on your filesystem?  If so, where is it located in relation to other modules that you can import?

Comment: Actually, I cannot find any .def file for library modules I can import. For example, I can compile 'FROM StrIO IMPORT WriteString, WriteLn;', but there is no StrIO.def on my filesystem (I guess the declaration is contained in some other installed file). There is no 'TimeDate.def' file either. For modules I have written myself I have to provide such a file (and it works).

Comment: So it seems to me that there are: (1) library modules that can be imported even though there is no .def file for them, (2) library modules without a .def file that cannot be imported, and (3) self-written modules with .def file that can be imported. For (2) I guess I either need to install some extra package or I need to use some compiler switches. I am still looking in the documentation to see if I can find some information on this.

Comment: I have installed the compiler following the instructions I found at http://www.nongnu.org/gm2/debian.html

Comment: Afraid to say that all my Modula-2 experience has been with DOS and Windows compilers.  Not familiar with the GNU compiler.  :-(

Comment: I had also worked with Modula-2 on MSDOS but it is a while ago. Thanks for the hints anyway.

Comment: @Brian Knoblauch: Did you use Modula-2 professionally? I used it a bit during my study. I am trying to implement some algorithms with it right now, to see how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately I've never had the opportunity to use it in a truly professional capacity.  I used it at home a bit back in the DOS days (up through the OS/2 and early Windows days).  I found it well suited to larger projects I was doing (for fun) back then.  I really haven't had any time for "fun"/home projects in quite awhile though, so my Modula-2 is rusty.  Luckily I found a couple simple utilities I could use it for at work (and I found out about the ADW compiler for Windows being released as freeware), so I've been able to get back to it a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a test system and was able to duplicate your problem.  Use "-flibs=pim,logitech"...  That worked for me and let me compile a basic test app without throwing the error about a missing definition file.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I have my little application running now.